# Facebook Graph API Get All Authorized Friends of those Users who authorized my app

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook app and made it public that is used by my .net web application, so there are users who login to my web application via facebook app through JS SDK.

In APP authorization for my web app i have explicitly asked permission of friends with public profile.

I want to create a console application that gets friends of the authorized users and i know app will only provide those friends that have also authorized the app.

**So from my console app when i try to get friends of a user with facebookId that has authorized my app but is not friend of Web APP Creator the result is empty.**

Is there any way to get required info?

Comment: is the app public? did ALL involved users authorize your app with the user_friends permission?

Comment: yes and i added it to question.

Comment: ok, because this sounded a bit weird: "permission of friends with public profile" - there is a specific user_friends permission.

Comment: yes luschn as by default public profile permission is granted and i explicitly asked user_friends permission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So i figure what i was doing wrong, I needed to store the useraccesstoken for users who are using my app and from there i can get information about them if they are offline and app can control the Life of access token short or long lived.

Thanks for responding though.